# IE8: jQuery append not working

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

jQuery append is working fine for all modern browser but for ie8 it is not working perfectly.

there is one issue.  i want to append the hyperlink . it works perfectly but in IE it is not appending Hyperlink.

here is my code:

```
<div id="recent-posts-2" class="sidebar_wrapper widget_recent_entries widget">                 

    <div class="sidebar_title clearfix">

        <h3 class="fl widget-title">Recent Posts</h3>

    </div>

    <ul class="news_ul clearfix">

        <li>
            <span class="post-date">June 3, 2013</span>
            <a href="http://domain.com/wood/china-conference-optional-tours/">China Conference &amp; optional tours</a>

        </li>

        <li>
            <span class="post-date">March 8, 2013</span>
            <a href="http://domain.com/wood/hello-world/">Russia: Forest Industry Competitiveness &amp; Export Outlook</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <span class="post-date">March 1, 2012</span>

            <a href="http://domain.com/wood/u-s-moulding-market-supply-options-outlook-to-2017/">U.S. Moulding Market &amp; Supply Options: Outlook to 2017</a>

        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(function() {

        jQuery('.widget_recent_entries .sidebar_title').append('<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/news" class="fr news_more">more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>');


    });

</script>
```

you can check this jsbin for iE8 it is not appending the hyperlink. need help.!

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/isAgEXAX/1/edit)

Comment: You've edited your question to change the code as per Tommy's suggestion, but didn't update your jsbin link to match. Did that change solve the problem or not?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the closing a tag in your jQuery.

```
</i></a>
```

Addtionally, IE11 (Edge mode), seems to choke on the `jquery(document).ready` type calls.  However, changing to the shortcut method `$(function(){code});` seems to work just fine.  The javascript below has been tested and confirmed to work with Chrome, IE8+.

```
$(function(){  
  $('.widget_recent_entries .sidebar_title').append('<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/news" class="fr news_more">more <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>');
  });
```

Lastly, keep in mind that jQuery 2.X only works with IE9 and higher (which was not the issue here, but a friendly reminder to those that may visit in the future).

http://jsbin.com/isAgEXAX/12/edit

Comment: @JackTorris  Still missing that closing tag.  Newer browsers will be more forgiving of broken html.  Add </a> to the end of your string to fix IE 8

Comment: so you mean to say it was not working because the </a> wasn't added?

Comment: @JackTorris - yes, did adding the closing tag fix IE?  Can't really test, on a tablet at the moment

Comment: @JackTorris - I am on a desktop now and can confirm that the edit above, using the latest jQuery 1.X version works across all browsers.  For some reason, IE11 (Edge) did not like the jQuery(document) calls, it kept saying jQuery was undefined.  However, IE8-10 had no problems with it.  When changed to the shortcut method above, it works flawlessly in all IE.